# How to sort items in Qt QListview using Qt.UserRole

Tags: python, qt, sorting, pyside, qlistview

I'm having some problem sorting the items in my `QListView` using values in a field I specified.

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

1. Detect faces in a collection of photos and display them in a `QListView`
2. Cluster the faces (images)
3. Update the view by placing items in the list (which are face images) belonging to the same cluster in together. Concretely, if item 1, 3, 5 are in one cluster and items 2, 4, 6 are in another, then items 1, 3, 5 should be displayed (in whatever permutations) before any of items 2, 4, 6 are displayed or vice versa.

The way I went about doing this is to set one of the `UserRole` field for each `QStandardItem` in my list to the cluster label and then try to get the `QStandardModel` to sort according to this `UserRole`. This would then display items in the same cluster (i.e. with the same cluster label in the `UserRole`) next to each other.

I'm able to set the `UserRole` successfully for the items but calling the sort function on the `QStandardModel` did not sort the items even though when I set the sort role to be the default `DisplayRole` (i.e. sort according to the text label of each face) it worked as intended.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code or offer an alternative method? I've googled sorting list and I found the following link on [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/itemviews-customsortfiltermodel.html%5d%5b1%5d) but as I'm quite new to Qt, I'm not able to adapt it to my situation.

Thanks in advance to any replies.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import os
from PySide.QtGui import QListView, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QIcon
from PySide.QtCore import Qt

class FacesView(QListView):
    """
    View to display detected faces for user to see and label.
    """
    UNCLUSTERED_LABEL = -1
    CLUSTER_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(FacesView, self).__init__(*args)
        self._dataModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.setModel(self._dataModel)
        # Layout items in batches instead of waiting for all items to be
        # loaded before user is allowed to interact with them.
        self.setLayoutMode(QListView.Batched)

    def updateFaceClusters(self, labels):
        """Update the cluster label for each face.
        @param labels: [1 x N] array where each element is an integer
        for the cluster the face belongs to."""

        assert(len(labels) == self._dataModel.rowCount())
        # Put the cluster label each item/face belong to in the
        # CLUSTER_ROLE field.
        for i in xrange(self._dataModel.rowCount()):
            index = self._dataModel.index(i, 0)
            self._dataModel.setData(index, labels[i], self.CLUSTER_ROLE)

        # Use cluster label as sort role
        self._dataModel.setSortRole(self.CLUSTER_ROLE)
        # This does NOT seem to sort the items even though it works fine
        # when sort role is the default Qt.DisplayRole.
        self._dataModel.sort(0)
        print("Finished updating face clusters")

    def itemsInList(self):
        """Returns the label for a face and the path to its image.
        @return: (label, path)"""
        items = []
        for i in xrange(self._dataModel.rowCount()):
            label =  self._dataModel.index(i, 0).data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            imagePath = self._dataModel.index(i, 0).data(Qt.UserRole)
            clusterLabel = self._dataModel.index(i, 0).data(self.CLUSTER_ROLE)
            items.append((imagePath, label, clusterLabel))

        return items

    def addItem(self, label, imagePath):
        """Add an item to list view
        @param label: The label associated with the item.
        @param imagePath: Path to image for the icon."""
        if os.path.exists(imagePath):
            icon = QIcon(imagePath)
        else:
            icon = QIcon(':/res/Unknown-person.gif')

        item = QStandardItem(icon, label)
        item.setEditable(True)
        # Add image path to the UserRole field.
        item.setData(imagePath, Qt.UserRole)
        # Add cluster label to image. CLUSTER_ROLE is where I intend
        # to put the item's cluster label.
        item.setData(self.UNCLUSTERED_LABEL, self.CLUSTER_ROLE)
        # Prevent an item from dropping into another item.
        item.setDropEnabled(False)
        # Add item to list indirectly by adding it to the model.
        self._dataModel.appendRow(item)

    def clear(self):
        self._dataModel.clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. So there must be something wrong with how you are using it. How are you generating the cluster labels?

Here's a test script using your `FacesView` class that sorts as you intended:

```
from random import randint
from PySide.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from facesview import FacesView

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.list = FacesView(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        labels = []
        self.list.model().setRowCount(0)
        for row in range(10):
            labels.append(randint(0, 3))
            text = 'Item(%d) - Cluster(%d)' % (row, labels[-1])
            self.list.addItem(text, 'icon.png')
        self.list.updateFaceClusters(labels)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi. Firstly, thanks for your reply. I've tried your test code and indeed the FacesView class sorting works. I followed your example by displaying the cluster label in the text label of each face icon and it seems that the clustering is performed correctly but those items with the same cluster labels are still not next to each other.

Comment: I suspect the sorting didn't work because of how I configured my list. FacesView's viewMode property was originally set to IconMode and its movement property was set to static. Changing viewMode to ListMode and movement to Snap did not help. Any idea which properties I should check? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I figured it out. You are correct, the problem is with the labels, specifically the "type" of the labels. I got the cluster labels from a library that returned them as a numpy array with dtype=int32. For some reason, even though the code was able to use the values in it to update the text label and the CLUSTER_ROLE field, it was unable to sort the elements using them. If I convert the numpy array to a list using "labels.tolist()" or map the elements to integers using "labels = map(int, labels", the sorting worked. Thanks!

Comment: What does Qt.UserRole + 1 imply here. ?

Comment: @nish It allows sorting by a custom data type, rather than a simple textual sort. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021010/984421) regarding item data roles).