# Message displaying in QListWidget/View on boolean condition

Tags: python, listview, pyqt, message-queue

I've some boolean variables. Each variable is associated to a string message.
I want to display the message in a QListWidget (or QListView) if the variable is True and hide it when the variable is False.

I also want to sort these messages by time of apparition.

Do you have some ideas/examples on how to do it ?
I'm not necessarily looking for a ready-made program, but at least a few paths to explore

Thanks !

Edit:

```
bMessage1, bMessage2, ... <= some boolean variables

sMessage1Text = "Message associated with bMessage1 variable"
sMessage2Text = "Message associated with bMessage2 variable"
...
```

(For now, i don't know wich is the best method to associate boolean var with string var to do what I want.)

Expected output :

If bMessage1 become True and then bMessage2 become, the QlistView/Widget should display :

```
Message associated with bMessage1 variable
Message associated with bMessage2 variable
```

If bMessage2 become True and then bMessage1 become, the QlistView/Widget should display :

```
Message associated with bMessage2 variable
Message associated with bMessage1 variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

I'm storing the messages as a dict which associate the variable name with information (Boolean for hidden status, Message label string, sort order info) :

```
self.aMessages = {"bMessage1": [False, "This is the message 1", 0],
                  "bMessage2": [False, "This is the message 2", 0],
                  "bMessage3": [False, "This is the message 3", 0],
                  "bMessage4": [False, "This is the message 4", 0],
                  "bMessage5": [False, "This is the message 5", 0]}
```

And the model based on `QStandardItemModel` :

```
class MessageListModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
                status = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                if status == True:
                    return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))
                elif status == False:
                    return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
        return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)

    def addItem(self, label, value):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(label)
        item.setEditable(False)
        item.setData(value, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1)
        item.setDropEnabled(False)
        self.appendRow(item)
```

Then, the model filling :

```
tm = MessageListModel()
for msg in self.aMessages.itervalues():
    tm.addItem(msg[1], msg[0])
ListView.setModel(tm)
```

and a thread to update the model :

```
class MessagesUpdateThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.exiting = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while not self.exiting:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateMessages()"))
            self.sleep(1)
```

And the slot for update and sort the model :

```
def updateMessages(self):
    MsgList = self.aMessages.values()
    model = self.ui.Messages.model()

    for i in xrange(len(MsgList)):
        value = MsgList[i][0]

        index = model.index(i, 0)
        model.setData(index, MsgList[i][1])
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        model.setData(index, MsgList[i][2], QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1)
        self.ui.Messages.setRowHidden(i, not value)
    del MsgList
    model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1)
    model.sort(0)
```

Then connect the slot to the thread signal :

```
self.m = MessagesUpdateThread()
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.m, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateMessages()"), self.updateMessages)
self.m.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string_list = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"]
variable_list = [True,True,False,True]
display_list = [string_list[i] for i,v in enumerate(variable_list) if v]
```

is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah, maybe i can fill the QlistView model with something like this. With a 3rd timestamp list to sort on.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `QListView` with a Model. You can fill the model by creating `QStandardItem()` and adding extra information to the `QStandardItem` by using `item.setData(data,role)`

The extra information you add should be whether the row is visible and an index of some kind (integer/timestamp/whatever) that indicates the order in which the rows should be sorted. Each piece of information corresponds to a different role, so you might assign the role `QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1` to whether a row is visible and `QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2` to the sort order information.

You can then write a function that uses `listview.setRowHidden()` to update whether rows are shown or hidden when you modify the model.

Finally you can tell the view to sort the rows by a particular role in the model using `model.setSortRole()`. When you modify the model to show a row (and call your function mentioned above) you can also modify the data in the model for the role that determines the sort order.

I haven't gone into too many specifics here because you said you just wanted some ideas, but most of this has come from another stack overflow post, so check out that if you need some more concrete example code (or just ask me and I'll expand on anything you get stuck on).

See: [How to sort items in Qt QListview using Qt.UserRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882980/how-to-sort-items-in-qt-qlistview-using-qt-userrole)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've updated my post. For now, I'm stuck with the `setRowHidden` function. Maybe I can clear the model and refill it but I think it's not a good solution. Do you have another one ?

Comment: what do you mean you are stuck with `setRowHidden`? is it not working correctly? How so? Maybe you can post a complete example python file on something like pastebin so I can understand better (trying to decipher the code you posted in an answer below is difficult because it is broken up into chunks and it isn't clear how it all fits together)