# What is the "role" argument in QTableWidgetItem.data(self, int *role*)?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidgetitem

I am looking through the documentation at:

- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#data

I can put the line `IDList.append(item.data())` into my code, and print that as the correct value. But weirdly, after that line, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: QTableWidgetItem.data(int): not enough arguments

I don't know why the error message comes after the print line, but I don't think that should be important. What does the documentation mean by "int *role*"? Can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An item has many kinds of data associated with it, such as text, font, background, tooltip, etc. The `role` is a value from the [ItemDataRole enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) that allows you to specify which kind of data you want.

Some of these items of data also have an accessor function. So these two lines of code are equivalent:

```
font = item.font()
font = item.data(QtCore.Qt.FontRole)
```

The data roles are extensible. You can use any values starting at `Qt.UserRole` to associate a custom role with your own data:

```
MyRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2
item.setData(MyRole, [1, 2, 3])
...
data = item.data(MyRole)
```

Comment: How do I know what role to use? is there a list somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see them in the link you added. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to get an Int from my item with data(). which role do I use for this? is there something like .number() that I can use in the item?

Comment: @PaulJackways. Are you using Python2? If you are, `data()` will return a `QVariant`, so you can use `.toInt()` to get a Python `int`. However, a much better solution is to follow the advice in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21223060/984421), which will get rid of `QVariant` altogether. You can also do the same for `QString`, so you don't have to keep converting with `str` all the time.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4, but I will try that anyway.

Comment: I tried adding `import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)` and going `IDList.append(item[0].data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))` and `IDList.append(item[0].data())`, neither of which worked.

Comment: @PaulJackways. In that case, please ignore my previous comment. I don't quite understand the problem you have, though. How did you set the data?

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is get the value of the QTableWidgetItem. It is an integer, and I am trying to get it out of a QTableWidgetItem in a list of QTableWidgetItems I want to do exactly what QTableWidgetItem.text() does but for an integer.

Comment: There's no special method for this: just do `int(item.text())` or `float(item.text())`.

Comment: I am trying that, but I am getting this: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`
when using `IDvar = item[0].text()`, `print(IDvar)`

I have checked, and I am sure that the item is a QTableWidgetItem.

Comment: @PaulJackways. Yes, that is exactly what should happen if you try to convert an invalid string to an `int`. An empty string is not a valid integer. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: it isn't meant to be an empty string. I am trying to get the data that is in the item that is displayed in my QTable. 

I tried this:

    `def log_change(self, item):`, 
        `self.table.blockSignals(False)`, 
        `print("item row")`, 
        `print(item.row())`, 
        `#self.changed_items.append(self.table.item(item.row(),1)`, 
        `print(self.table.item(item.row(),1).text())` 

The print statement prints nothing.

Comment: @PaulJackways. None of this has anything to do with the original question here. Please start a new question, and show all the relevant code.